Why is cargo nextest choosing not to run some of my tests after finding them?
I just ran a set of tests I have been developing.
All of a sudden I start getting a summary like this:
Summary [   0.598s] 26/28 tests run: 24 passed, 2 failed, 0 skipped

More specifically I comment out enough tests to get a "straight number" of tests run. This is the report:
Summary [   0.588s] 27 tests run: 26 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped

Then I add this test to mod tests:
#[test]
fn do_test() -> Result<()> {
    assert!(false);
    Ok(())
}

The report I now get is:
Summary [   0.607s] 26/28 tests run: 24 passed, 2 failed, 0 skipped

"2 failed": seems sensible. But more difficult: it's telling me 2 fewer tests actually passed. Equally puzzling, all of a sudden it's "unsure" how many tests have been run.
Update due to cafce25's comments
In fact "26/28 tests" means "there were 28 tests, but only 26 are run". So then the question is: why are those 2 non-run tests not being run?
A significant fact could possibly be that I'm using the crate mockall here, including directive #[double].
Can anyone explain what's going on and where in nextest documentation this may be explained?
More details
So this is a run, showing that at the start of the run 29 tests are announced ... but the summary report at the end shows that 4 tests were not run:
(doc_indexer) D:\...\populate_index_module>cargo nextest run -v
   Compiling populate_index_module v0.1.0 (D:\...\populate_index_module)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 4.33s
    Starting 29 tests across 4 binaries
        PASS [   0.031s] populate_index_module auxiliaries::tests::working_up_from_app_execution_cwd_finds_doc_indexer_project_root_dir
        PASS [   0.025s] populate_index_module handling_framework::tests::unreadable_zip_complaint_causes_continue_not_error_propagation::case_1
        ...
        PASS [   0.088s] populate_index_module::test_1 ldocs_contain_more_than_one_para
        FAIL [   0.232s] populate_index_module text_document::tests::deliberately_failing_test

... end of test run report:
        PASS [   0.557s] populate_index_module::test_1 all_text_in_files_is_correctly_caught::case_2
------------
     Summary [   0.599s] 25/29 tests run: 22 passed, 3 failed, 0 skipped
        FAIL [   0.232s] populate_index_module text_document::tests::deliberately_failing_test
        FAIL [   0.266s] populate_index_module::test_1 framework_init_populates_the_index_by_submitting_bulk_inserts
        FAIL [   0.208s] populate_index_module::test_1 test_thing
error: test run failed

NB the "Starting" list at the start in fact only lists 17 results above. There are more "total" tests because I'm using crate rstest in order to parameterise tests.
Weird stuff
cargo nextest has quite a few options and flags (try cargo nextest run --help) ... I found one called --run-ignored. So ran this:
(doc_indexer) D:\...\populate_index_module>cargo nextest run --run-ignored all

The results are pretty weird: sometimes it runs all 29 tests. Sometimes 26/29. Sometimes 23/29. Sometimes 27/29. ... At this point I'm going over to the Github location for nextest to raise an issue. But if anyone can provide any explanation I'd like to hear it. Bear in mind that none of these are skipped tests, as decided by me: the decision not to run these tests is entirely nextest's.

It all adds up though 26 of the 28 tests were run, 24 of them passed 2 failed for a total of 26

Ok, but then the question is: Why has adding this dummy test led it to decide there are "26/28" tests, rather than "28" tests? I think there are 28 tests, simple. nextest has concluded something different. I'm trying to understand.

There are 28 tests and 26 of them were run, that's what "26/28 tests run" means, literally "26 of 28 tests run".

Ah... excellent, thanks. But then... (inevitably) why is it not running those 2 non-run tests?

In fact this was the intended behaviour, as by default nextest runs in fail-fast mode.
There were 2 things I had to sort out.
I learnt that nextest executes tests in parallel. Two of my tests involved creating some files and directories in a temporary directory tree, before cleaning up at teardown. Rust has a function std::env::temp_dir() which returns a PathBuf for, it appeared, this kind of purpose. It doesn't actually create the directory returned.
Anyway I realised that the making of these files and directories was clashing. I went out of my way to ensure that these 2 tests couldn't confuse the paths of their temporary files.
Turns out this is not "best practice" according to the nextest creator. She recommends crate tempfile, tempfile::tempfile, or better still her own crate, camino-tempfile. The temp dirs in the latter are thread-safe.
... but in fact that wasn't the cause of the problem. Even with completely separated test resources, I was still getting the problem, particularly when there were lots of fails.
So she also recommends using the switch --no-fail-fast. This appears to have done the trick.
I'm not 100% clear about what running without that switch means: because I would have thought that running a test suite on "fail-fast" would mean that the first fail would stop the run. But in those non-completing runs I was usually getting multiple fails. Most probably the explanation for that is, precisely, that these tests are all running in parallel, so shutting down the run doesn't mean you always only get one fail.
... the other puzzle being that, despite not running with that "no fail fast" switch, I hadn't previously experienced this: maybe it tends to start kicking in above a certain volume of tests? My machine has a core-count of 8, but I'm pretty sure that it was only above about 20 tests that this non-running of some tests started to happen.
